# Sum values from multiple selects gives strange results in total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I tried to add value price tag several selects but I get some strange results. 
I would appreciate help to know that certain numbers do not sum well. 
Here I leave the link to the example jsfiddle.net 
http://jsfiddle.net/pgy74r1k/

javascript Function:

```
sumValues('#priceList', '#totalPrice');
function sumValues(list,total){
  var allListElements = $( "select" );
  var sum = 0;
  $( list ).find( allListElements ).each(function() {
    sum += Number($('option:selected', this).attr('price'));
  });
  $(total).empty();
  $(total).append(sum+' €');

}
```

html Code:

```
<div id="priceList">    
  <select class="participant" name="price1" style="width: 100%" onchange="sumValues('#priceList', '#totalPrice')">
        <option value="0" price="0"> 0€ </option>
        <option value="1" price="10.62" selected="selected"> 10.62€ </option>  
  </select>  
  <select class="participant" name="price2"
 style="width: 100%" onchange="sumValues('#priceList', '#totalPrice')">
         <option value="0" price="0"> 0€ </option>
         <option value="1" price="13" selected="selected"> 13€ </option>  
  </select>   
</div>      
<strong id="totalPrice"></strong>
```

Comment: If you try running `13+10.62` directly, you'll see the strange result has nothing to do with your HTML or DOM scripting. Your issue is caused purely by how floating point math works, which is addressed directly in [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
$(total).append(sum.toFixed(2)+' €');
```

**EDIT**: well not sure what you call a strange result?!